# NSUserDefault give EXC_BAD_ACCESS trying to get values

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, exc-bad-access

I'm using NSUserDefaults in my app to store some flag values. My function increases the value each time that a condition has occurred. Occasionally it works, but most of the time it crashes and get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS message.

```
var sample1: Int = countWord.integer(forKey: "countWord1")
var sample2: Int = countWord.integer(forKey: "countWord2")
var sample3: Int = countWord.integer(forKey: "countWord3")
```

Those are the lines where I get the error.

**EDIT**

This is how I initialize and set`countword`

```
let countWord = UserDefaults.standard
countWord.set(sample1+1, forKey: "countWord1")
```

Application crashes after repeatedly iterated function

Comment: What's `countWord`?

Comment: Can you show how you initialized countWord ? Did you try with this : `countWord.integer(forKey: "countWord1") as Int! ?? 0`, It won't crash, I think it crash because there is nothing in countWord1 / countWord2 / countWord3

Comment: I already tried to use this method but still crashes

Comment: @Aximem `integer(forKey:` returns a non-optional `Int` in Swift 3. *If the specified key does not exist, this method returns 0.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think these are the lines your app is crashing. For **exc-bad-access** you usually have to trace way back. You can use **Instrument** to trace it.

The variables defined in the controller and methods are well handled by ARC. This usually happens when you have two controller, for example, **ViewController A** is trying to access **ViewController B**'s strong variable after **ViewController B** is deallocated.

Comment: Actually I use this flag in two different controller. I will try to trace it